# Конвертировать png в gif сохранив прозрачность. Tkinter. Python

Tags: python, gui, tkinter, gif

Я конвертировал png картинку в gif с помощью следуещого кода, но все прозрачние пиксели стали black. Вот код:

```
    lpath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\Chrome\\Application\\56.0.2924.87\\VisualElements\\logo.png"
    img = PIL.Image.open(lpath)
    resized = img.resize((75,75))


    newImage = PIL.Image.new(resized.mode, resized.size)
    newImage.paste(resized)


    newImage.save(os.getcwd()+"\\res\\out.gif")
```

Как превратить все черние пиксели в прозрачние?

Comment: Таки проблема в том, что GIF, вроде как, прозрачность не поддерживает, нету в нем альфа-канала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте эту строку

```
newImage = PIL.Image.new(resized.mode, resized.size)
```

заменить на эту

```
newImage = PIL.Image.new(resized.mode, resized.size, color=(0, 0, 0, X))
```

где X либо 0, либо 255

P.S
http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.new

Comment: пробовал 0 и 255, все одно не работает